# EF Core database operation throws error "Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded"

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core 3.1 have the following code

```
public void Update()
{
    Client client = new Client();
    client.ClientId = 1;
    client.Name = "New Client 1";

    dbContext.Entry<Client>(client).State = EntityState.Modified;
    dbContext.Entry<Client>(client).Property(x => x.IdentityNumber).IsModified = false;

    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

which produces the following SQL an successfully updates the column

```
UPDATE [Client] 
SET [Name] = @p0
WHERE [ClientId] = @p1;

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

However when I change the `ClientId = 4` which is an entry that was deleted from database it produces the same SQL query but throws the following error

> Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded

The error message is clear but I don't understand why it does not work as SQL Server works (0 row(s) affected) and instead throws this error.

How can I simulate the 0 row(s) affected SQL Server behavior using EF Core?

I do not want to query the database first if the row exists and then update. The above code is a sample. In my methods I have lists with many clients that I need to update at once and it takes long to do that using the first check if exists and then update.

Comment: I'm guessing it is because you are changing it to update when a record of that id does not exist.  you need to insert the record before you can update.

Comment: @Hogan if you read my post carefully I state that the record was deleted

Comment: I was not sure but if the record has been deleted how do you expect to update it?

Answer (score 0):

> I do not want to query the database first if the row exists and then update.

This is the crux of your problem and the reason for the error.

Our approach, and a common one I believe, is to use Dapper when manipulating a lot of data, and limit EF to Load -> Edit -> Save operations on single or very few entities.

Comment: I was thinking to use a hybrid model as well with Dapper but I wanted to keep a consistency across the system and use only EF Core. There is not any way to achieve what I need with EF Core right?

Comment: We initially went down the route of overriding some of the entity management stuff in EF to try to get away with EF only - this was several versions back now, I don't know if this approach would work better with the latest version. We were not successful, and caused a few really really nasty bugs. I don't want to disparage EF too much - it's great at what it does. But if you don't need or can't afford the overhead it's just not the right tool for the job.

Comment: Well as you said will keep simple stuff for EF Core and go with Dapper for batch ops

Comment: If you are open to EF Core extensions, there do appear to be some out there although I cannot vouch for them. But, there do seem to be more options now than before, and if they do play nicely with EF's cached/working data, you'll be better off than we were.

Comment: Can you suggest any?

Comment: I'm sorry, no - we went our own route and honestly, I don't think I could be happier than I am with Dapper. But I saw a few promising libraries when I searched for "ef core batch update".